# Share games between PSN users

Tags: psn

It's been a while since I've bought games from the PSN store. In a lot of games' descriptions, I've seen a section that says "2-n Network players", where n is some larger number.

Does this indicate that I am able to share my games with friends?

If yes, does this mean that my friends can play the entire game? By that I mean, would he/she be able to play the story mode of the game? Could they even play the game online in online rooms?

Or is this just indicating that I can play together with friends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what this means. This is not saying you can share your license with others, it is saying how many players can play together in an online game.

For instance, from the [PES 2017 store page](https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-us/games/pro-evolution-soccer-2017/cid=UP0101-CUSA04984_00-PES2017000000000?scope=sceapp&smcid=sceapp&psappver=4.20.9:home), it says "Network Players 2-22".

[image: network players]

This means that as few as 2 people can play in an online game together, but so can as many as 22 players. This doesn't mean you can purchase a game and share your license.

As for the part above it that says "1-4 Players", that is referring to how many can play on a single system.

It's somewhat obvious, but if you buy a physical copy, you can let as many people as you want borrow it to let them play, but you'll still need the disc if you want to play yourself.

Comment: You are totally right. Since I saw a share option for the games, I thought maybe it's for sharing the license.

Comment: @AliBahraminezhad no, if I had to guess, it's for sharing the game with Shareplay.